# link from mobile website to mobile phone navigation

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I want a button on my mobile website for navigation. Not website navigation, but once you press the button it brings up the navigation app on Android & iOS to give driving directions to a place of business.

Been searching and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question. Here is the code:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
        $map_slug='https://maps.apple.com';
     else
        $map_slug='https://maps.google.com'; ?>
    <div class="footer-bar">
        <div class="wrap">
            <p>&copy; Copyright 2009-<?php echo date("Y"); ?> allies4me &middot; All Rights Reserved</p>
            <ul class="contacts-list mob-visible">
            <li><a href="<?php echo $map_slug?>/?daddr=30.309940,-97.917470"></i>Navigate</a></li></ul>
```

This lets me launch iPhone map on iPhones & Google maps on Android.

Here is where I found more info on the answer:
https://support.prontoforms.com/entries/25049627-How-To-Launch-a-Map-App-from-a-Mobile-Form